# Remote OpenVPN LAN unreachable on Linux laptop, but reachable on Android

Tags: networking, router, vpn, lan, openvpn

First I should mention that the local and and remote LANs sit on 192.168.1.0. My local/client LAN router is sitting at 192.168.1.1. The remote LAN router is also sitting on 192.168.1.1. Actual VPN server is sitting on 192.168.1.73. What I want is to type 192.168.1.1 in the browser and reach the remote LAN. I have been able to do this on my Android phone, but not on my Linux laptop. I use absolutely identical settings on both devices. The reason behind this effort is that I want to be able to access my remote/VPN LAN regardless of the network I am currently connected at the moment - I travel a lot. Here's the config files:

server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/crt-openvpn.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/key-openvpn.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh4096.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0

cipher AES-256-CBC

tls-version-min 1.2

tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256

auth SHA256

comp-lzo

user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"

status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3

log-append /var/log/openvpn
status /tmp/vpn.status 10
```

client.conf:

```
client
remote 'name' 1194 - removed actual address since this is public
dev tun
proto udp

resolv-retry infinite
nobind

ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/key.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/key.key

ns-cert-type server

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 1

cipher AES-256-CBC

tls-version-min 1.2

tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256

auth SHA256

comp-lzo

user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

verb 3
```

I have also set up dnsmasq to make sure DNS queries are dealt with on the VPN server. This works fine. The only issue remaining as I said before is when I try to load 192.168.1.1 from the client. On my Android phone, this redirects to the remote router as I want it to. But on my Linux machine it goes to my local router, which I do not want. I fail to understand how and why the laptop sees the local LAN when I have instructed it to communicate everything through the remote LAN.

What I have discovered is that if I change my local LAN to 192.168.2.0, I am able to reach 192.168.1.1 on the remote LAN. But since I travel a lot and cannot always connect to a network I manage, I cannot ensure the local subnet will not match the remote one. Thus I wish to be able to reach the remote LAN regardless of the local setup. How is this achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using 192.168.0.0/24 or 192.168.1.0/24 (and even 192.168.2.0/24 etc) you are setting your self up to encounter routing conflicts.  The best solution is to renumber all  the networks you do manage to very unique ranges from RFC1918.  examples LAN1:10.209.121.0/24 LAN2: 10.209.122.0/24